# How to consolidate Jquery into cleaner format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help consolidating my code.  This is the working code but I can't seem to get it when I try and simplify.

I wrote it with jquery and I've new to javascript as a whole.  It's basically a loop but I'm not sure how to loop it through.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// house_one
    $('.house_one')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_one').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_one').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.box_one')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_one').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_one').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
//house_two
    $('.house_two')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_two').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_two').removeClass('hover');
    });
            $('.box_two')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_two').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_two').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
// house_three
    $('.house_three')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_three').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_three').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.box_three')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_three').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_three').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
// house_four
    $('.house_four')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_four').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_four').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.box_four')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_four').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_four').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
// house_five
    $('.house_five')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_five').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_five').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.box_five')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_five').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_five').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
// house_six
    $('.house_six')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_six').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_six').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.box_six')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_six').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_six').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
// house_seven
    $('.house_seven')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_seven').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_seven').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.box_seven')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_seven').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_seven').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
// house_eight
    $('.house_eight')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.box_eight').addClass('hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.box_eight').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('.box_eight')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.house_eight').addClass('house_hover');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.house_eight').removeClass('house_hover');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you wrote it in javascript, using jquery. jquery is not a language, despite what many people think....

Comment: will edit for future visitors.

Comment: You could use jQuery's find and replace and instead of using the word "one" use numbers like 1 and use those numbers to perform some test.

Comment: Have you considered trying to implement this using CSS rather than JS/Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setupHovers(house, box){
    house = $(house);
    box   = $(box);
    house.hover(function(){  box.toggleClass('hover');  });
    box.hover(function(){    house.toggleClass('house_hover');  });
}

boxHouseArray = ['one','two','three','four','five','six' ...]; //

for(boxHouse in boxHouseArray){
   setupHovers('.house_'+boxHouse, '#box_'+boxHouse);
}
```

or even better change your markup slightly:

```
<a href="/interiors/house_1" class="house_list">House 04</a>
 and
<div class="box"></div>
```

now you can go like this:

```
var houses = $('.house_list'), boxes = $('.box');
houses.hover(function(){
    boxes.eq( houses.index(this) ).toggleClass('hover'); 
});
boxes.hover(function(){
    houses.eq( boxes.index(this) ).toggleClass('house_hover'); 
});
```

The idea here is no extra id's or markup, we simply use the order of the elements in the markup as our configuration. Lets say we mouse over the first box: `index(this)` will tell us if its the first box on the page and trigger the hover class on the first house via `eq`

Answer (score 3):

Just use two classes `box` and `house` and all of that can be reduced to this:

```
$('.house').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).closest('.box').toggleClass('hover')
})

$('.box').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).closest('.house').toggleClass('house_hover')
})
```

**Edit:**

If you're markup doesn't work with `closest()` because the elements don't share the same container then use ids in addition to the general classes.

```
$('.house').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
  // Assuming id = house_one (or two, three etc...)
  var id = this.id.split('_')[1]
  $('#box_'+ id).toggleClass('hover')
})
```

Comment: You don't that's my point. You might need different ids, but classes are meant to be generic.

Comment: Hmmm... I've always understood id's for the old dev days.  Only use classes. I understand the difference, however, I don't use id's.  Maybe I should start... The problem I run into when I set a generic class is that only one box should have a hover effect for each item listed.  And, in the case you hover over the box, only one link should correspond to that box.  Wouldn't creating a generic class cause all the links to hover on any box?